# Marginal Distribution of a Stochastic Block Model?

Tags: marginal-distribution, graph-theory, consistency

Let us say I have a Stochastic Block Model i.e. a random vector $X^{(n)} = [x_1,...,x_n]$ where $P(x_i = c) = P_{c}$, where $c \in \{1,...,u\}$, and a random simple undirected graph represented by $Y^{(n)} = [y_{12},y_{13},...,y_{i<j},...y_{n-1,n}]$, where $y_{ij}\in \{\ 0,1\}$ and $P(y_{ij}=1) = W_{x_i,x_j}$ and $P(y_{ij}=0) = 1- W_{x_i,x_j}$. Now,

$$P(X^{(n)},Y^{(n)}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}P_{x_i}\prod_{1\leq i<j \leq n}W_{x_i,x_j}^{y_{i<j}} (1-W_{x_i,x_j})^{(1-y_{i<j})} \tag{1}$$

Now, as per this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.3054.pdf) and it's [supplementary material](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/12-AOS1044SUPP). An SBM is projective, which in my understanding must mean that :

If I take the first $m$ entries of $X^{(n)}$ say $X^{\downarrow m} = [x_1,...,x_m]$ and analogously $Y^{\downarrow m} = [y_{12},...,y_{m-1,m}]$ then the marginal distribution of $(X^{\downarrow m},Y^{\downarrow m})$ must be :

$$ = \prod_{i=1}^{m}P_{x_i}\prod_{1\leq i<j \leq m}W_{x_i,x_j}^{y_{i<j}} (1-W_{x_i,x_j})^{(1-y_{i<j})} \tag{2}$$

i.e. it is no different from having taken only $m$ nodes to start with i.e. $$P(X^{(m)},Y^{(m)})= P(X^{\downarrow m},Y^{\downarrow m}) \tag{3}$$

How may I prove this statement ? Is it even correct ? The [supplementary material](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/12-AOS1044SUPP) proposition 1, in principle should be proving this, but I don't see how this follows?

Note: That the marginalisation of $P(X^{(n)},Y^{(n)})$ to get $P(X^{\downarrow m},Y^{\downarrow m}) $, will involve probabilities of $[y_{1,m+1}...,y_{m,n}]$. Hence, I am not sure if trivial application of the law of total probability works.